# webpack cli Error - You must compile JS to extract vendor code

Tags: node.js, npm, composer-php, laravel-6

```
bone@bone:/home/webb/fishy$ npm run prod

> @ prod /home/webb/fishy
> npm run production


> @ production /home/webb/fishy
> mix --production

[webpack-cli] Error: You must compile JS to extract vendor code
    at Extract.webpackEntry (/home/webb/fishy/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Extract.js:46:19)
    at /home/webb/fishy/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentRegistrar.js:112:53
    at /home/webb/fishy/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:39:62
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Dispatcher.fire (/home/webb/fishy/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:39:47)
    at Mix.dispatch (/home/webb/fishy/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:248:32)
    at WebpackConfig.buildEntry (/home/webb/fishy/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:62:24)
    at WebpackConfig.build (/home/webb/fishy/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:27:20)
    at Mix.build (/home/webb/fishy/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:89:35)
    at module.exports (/home/webb/fishy/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:16:16)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ production: `mix --production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/free/.npm/_logs/2022-12-14T13_08_33_629Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ prod: `npm run production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/free/.npm/_logs/2022-12-14T13_08_33_652Z-debug.log
```

Newbie here.Excuse my ignorance.first time to install npm.Someone knows or can explain what errors is all about?
my env:
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
node - v14.15.5
npm - v6.14.11
php - v7.4.3
composer - 2.4.4
laravel const VERSION = '6.18.15'

Comment: Can you edit the question to include what your webpack config looks like?

Comment: After i added some contents in .env file.I only have one error left which is "can't resolve vue-confirm-dialog"

Comment: webpack compiled successfully.thank you MysticSeagull for your assistance